# Capture invisible notebook image

Tags: notebooks

Is there anyway to grab an image of a notebook without it visibly opening? `CurrentNotebookImage[nb]` seems to force the notebook nb to become visible.

Comment: Does `Rasterize[nb]` work?

Comment: Do you work with notebook files or invisible notebook objects?

Comment: @b3m2a1 Not really, Rasterize will capture an image of the entire notebook, whereas CurrentNotebookImage will grab what fits on screen if it was opened - which is what I was wanting.

Comment: @Kuba I'm using both

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me either.

Comment: does `ImageCrop[
  Rasterize[#], {Full, Last[WindowSize /. Options[#, WindowSize]]}, 
  Bottom] &@n` work?