# How to convert a Java BufferedImage to a Mathematica Image?

Tags: image, java

*Mathematica*'s `CurrentScreenImage` is very buggy on multiple monitor setups, so Wolfram tech support has proposed to use .NET or Java frameworks to implement my own.

This is what I have so far:

```
Needs["JLink`"] 
ReinstallJava[] 
LoadJavaClass["java.awt.Toolkit"];
robot = JavaNew["java.awt.Robot"] 
img = robot@createScreenCapture[JavaNew[ "java.awt.Rectangle",Toolkit`getDefaultToolkit[]@getScreenSize[]]]
```

But, `img` is a `Java.awt.image.BufferedImage`.  How do I convert `img` to a *Mathematica*'s `Image`?  In particular, I'm concerned about memory leaks, so how do I do this in such a way, that I can grab a screen shot once per minute and not consume all memory after a day?

**UPDATE**

A had a concern of memory leaks.  In Ben's answer below, I appear to have hit a java memory leak.  Here's what's happening, if I do the appropriate preamble

```
Needs["JLink`"]
ReinstallJava[]
LoadJavaClass["java.awt.Toolkit"];
LoadJavaClass["javax.imageio.ImageIO"];
LoadJavaClass["java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream"];
robot = JavaNew["java.awt.Robot"]
```

Define a `getScreen` command as follows:

```
getScreen := Module[{},
  tmpImgBuffer = JavaNew["java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream"];
  ImageIO`write[
   robot@createScreenCapture[
     JavaNew[ "java.awt.Rectangle", 
      Toolkit`getDefaultToolkit[]@getScreenSize[]]], "png", 
   tmpImgBuffer];
  ImportByteArray[ByteArray@Mod[tmpImgBuffer@toByteArray[], 2^8], 
   "PNG"]
  ]
 Table[getScreen // ImageDimensions // Total, 1000] // Total
```

Then, `getScreen` consumes all Java memory very consistently after 30 calls.  I have screen size of 2560,1440.

Comment: Replace `Module` with [`JavaBlock`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/JLink/ref/JavaBlock.html) and insert `robot = JavaNew["java.awt.Robot"];`, to prevent memory leaking.

Comment: An older question: "[How to create a screen shot of a notebook](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56065/280)."

Comment: Related: "[Capture invisible notebook image](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/192597/280)."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Courtesy of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10247123/11965951), one solution is to use java to get the `PNG` data then import it to Mathematica as `Image`.

For that you need to import the following class:

```
LoadJavaClass["javax.imageio.ImageIO"];
LoadJavaClass["java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream"];
```

Assuming:

```
LoadJavaClass["java.awt.Toolkit"];

robot = JavaNew["java.awt.Robot"];

img = robot@createScreenCapture[JavaNew[ "java.awt.Rectangle",Toolkit`getDefaultToolkit[]@getScreenSize[]]]
```

Write the image data in our variable:

```
temp = JavaNew["java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream"];
ImageIO`write[img, "png", temp];
```

Since Mathematica read the numbers as `Integer8` instead of `UnsignedInteger8`, I used `Mod` to convert:

```
ImportByteArray[ByteArray@Mod[temp@toByteArray[], 2^8], "PNG"]
```

### Update 1

> As for @Alexey_Popkov's comment, I decided to extend this answer to get screenshots like `CurrentScreenImage`.

First I thought with help of `AbsoluteOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize]` and `AbsoluteOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowMargins]` it should be easy, but I realize their unit is not in pixel!

Exploring functions with `Names`, introduced me to `RobotTools` context which I think is similar to `"java.awt.Robot"` because of some common methods. It has a helpful function named `GetWindowRectangle` which works like `CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowMargins]` but doesn't include `Automatic` if you maximize. Since they also have different units than pixels, I used `Rescale` to interpolate to the actual pixel (but in some cases, it could <10 pixels off)

Requirements:

```
Needs["JLink`"];

LoadJavaClass /@ {"java.awt.Toolkit", "java.awt.Robot", 
   "java.awt.Rectangle", "java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream", 
   "javax.imageio.ImageIO"};

Needs["RobotTools`"];
```

```
ClearAll[cCurrentNotebookImage];
cCurrentNotebookImage[] := 
 Block[{xMin, yMin, xMax, yMax, xLimit, yLimit, screenSizeX, 
   screenSizeY, temp, robot},

  {xLimit, yLimit} = 
   System`Convert`TeXDump`getWindowSizeFromScreenRectangle[];

  {{xMin, yMin}, {xMax, yMax}} = Floor@RobotTools`GetWindowRectangle[];
  
  JavaBlock[

   (*screen size in their unit*)
   screenSizeX = Toolkit`getDefaultToolkit[]@getScreenSize[]@width;

   screenSizeY = Toolkit`getDefaultToolkit[]@getScreenSize[]@height;
   
   (* clip extra pixels if windows is out of range *)
   {xMin, xMax} = Clip[{xMin, xMax}, {0, xLimit}];
   {yMin, yMax} = Clip[{yMin, yMax}, {0, yLimit}];

   (*interpolate*)
   {{xMin, xMax}, {yMin, yMax}} = 
    Floor@{Rescale[{xMin, xMax}, {0, xLimit}, {0, screenSizeX}], 
      Rescale[{yMin, yMax}, {38`, yLimit}, {0, screenSizeY - 13}]};
   
   robot = JavaNew["java.awt.Robot"];

   temp = JavaNew["java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream"];

   img = 
    robot@createScreenCapture[
      JavaNew["java.awt.Rectangle", xMin, yMin, xMax - xMin, 
       yMax - yMin]];

   ImageIO`write[img, "png", temp];

   ImportByteArray[ByteArray@Mod[temp@toByteArray[], 2^8], "PNG"]
   ]
  ]
```

<strike>If we consider `MaxMemoryUsed` is accurate on JLink calls, compared to `CurrentNotebookImage` using `RepeatedTiming` on version 13.1, it was ~30% slower but uses ~6 times less memory! (if you change the format from `PNG` to `JPG`, performance doesn't change but it significantly uses less memory, around 31 times less than `CurrentNotebookImage`!)</strike>

The remaining issues are:

1. On maximized windows, black pixels appear on top + taskbar at the bottom,
2. If you move windows out of range, the title bar may be clipped

Otherwise in not-maximized in-range windows, I didn't find any issue.

##### Advance User Note:

- `38` came from Mathematica offset, in maximize mode it shows `32.25` and not-maximized but sticks to the top, it shows `38.25`.
- `13` was found in experiments (works fine in windows), feel free to change it

### Update <strike>2</strike> 3

Thanks to @Alexey_Popkov, this new version is ~40% faster than `CurrentNotebookImage`, more accurate than the previous update and does not use undocumented functions.

```
ClearAll[cCurrentNotebookImage];
cCurrentNotebookImage[] := 
 Block[{xMin, yMin, xMax, yMax, screenSize, screenLimit, temp, robot, 
   windowMargins, width, height, windowWidth, windowHeight, ratio, 
   windowSize, 
   displayInformation = 
    First@SystemInformation["Devices", "ConnectedDisplays"]},
  
  (* screen size in the unit *)
  screenLimit = ("Region" /. displayInformation)[[All, 2]];
  
  (* ratio for each axis *)
  ratio = ("Resolution" /. 
      First[SystemInformation["Devices", "ScreenInformation"]])/72.;
  
  (* screen size in pixel - without taskbar *)
  screenSize = Round[screenLimit*ratio];
  
  (* current windows margin/size *)
  windowMargins = AbsoluteCurrentValue[WindowMargins];
  windowSize = AbsoluteCurrentValue[WindowSize] + {0, 35};
  
  If[NumberQ[windowMargins],
   (* maximized *)
   {xMin, yMin} = {0, 0}; {width, height} = screenSize;
   
   ,(* not maximized *)
   {xMin, 
     yMin} = {windowMargins[[1, 1]], windowMargins[[2, 2]]}*ratio // 
     Round;
   {width, height} = Round[windowSize*ratio];
   
   (* make x/y in range *)
   xMin = Clip[xMin + 8, {0, First@screenSize}];
   yMin = Clip[yMin + 2, {0, Last@screenSize}];
   
   (* make width/height in range - clip the part gets out of view *)
   width = Clip[width, {0, First@screenSize - xMin}];
   height = Clip[height, {0, Last@screenSize - yMin}];
   ];
  
  JavaBlock[
   robot = JavaNew["java.awt.Robot"];
   
   temp = JavaNew["java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream"];
   
   img = 
    robot@createScreenCapture[
      JavaNew["java.awt.Rectangle", xMin, yMin, width, height]];
   
   ImageIO`write[img, "png", temp];
   
   ImportByteArray[ByteArray@Mod[temp@toByteArray[], 2^8], "PNG"]
   ]
  ]
```

As a side note, I notice Mathematica have `` RobotTools`CaptureScreenshot `` context but I couldn't execute their functions (all of them are in the `Private` context).

`32.5` of `35` is for Mathematica's `WindowSize` not giving the full view range (it's -32.5 from `"Region"`), I added a little extra to make it snap (same goes for `8` and `2`).

### Update 4

Here is the `NetLink` version (faster than Java):

```
Needs["NETLink`"];

LoadNETType /@ {"System.Drawing.Graphics", 
   "System.IO.MemoryStream", 
   "System.Drawing.CopyPixelOperation", 
   "System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat"};

Module[{temp, g, memory},
 NETBlock[
  temp = NETNew["System.Drawing.Bitmap", 2560, 1080];
  g = Graphics`FromImage[temp];
  
  g@CopyFromScreen[0, 0, 0, 0, temp@Size, 
    CopyPixelOperation`SourceCopy];
  memory = NETNew["System.IO.MemoryStream"];
  
  temp@Save[memory, ImageFormat`Png];
  ImportByteArray[ByteArray@memory@ToArray[], "PNG"]
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: (+1) It is interesting that your code works *much* faster than `CurrentScreenImage[]`. May be you can show how to get a screenshot of a Notebook window, like `CurrentNotebookImage[]` (which is broken in version 13 on Windows)?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov thanks for the upvote. I updated the post.

Comment: What are robottools?  I'm not finding them in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Instead of `Rescale`, you could use the conversion coefficient `OptionValue[First@SystemInformation["Devices", "ConnectedDisplays"], "Scale"]` (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/260927/280)) to get pixels from printer's points returned by `AbsoluteCurrentValue[WindowMargins]` and `AbsoluteCurrentValue[WindowSize]`. But for some reason direct use of these values gives slightly shifted screenshot (your code also gives a screenshot, which is slightly extended at the bottom of the window).

Comment: Also, the whole screen size can be obtained as `OptionValue[First@SystemInformation["Devices", "ConnectedDisplays"], "PixelDimensions"]`.

Comment: `MaxMemoryUsed` doesn't include the memory used by Java. It is better to control the memory usage from `MemoryAvailable[]` or `SystemInformation["Machine", "MemoryAvailable"]`.

Comment: The conversion from points to pixels is discussed in the "Possible Issues" section on the Docs page for [`SystemInformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SystemInformation.html).

Comment: @John `RobotTools` just like many other useful functions and contexts is undocumented. Using them may includes possible crashes on wrong input, incompatibility with other/feature versions and etc.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thank you for all of the suggestions. I updated the post base on them. It's now faster and more accurate.

Comment: Thank you again. New version work perfectly with version 12.3.1 and almost perfectly with version 13.1.0 (the screenshot is still slightly extended at the bottom of the window).

Comment: I think that we shouldn't apply `Round` before multiplying by `xyRatios`: the values returned by `AbsoluteCurrentValue` are real *by design*, hence only after converting them to pixels we expect to get integers.

Comment: You can avoid the hardcoded value `40` (which depends on the system settings) by using `"ScreenArea" /. First[SystemInformation["Devices", "ScreenInformation"]]` instead for getting the area without the taskbar. Also, the screen resolution is always equal in the horizontal and vertical directions, so we can safely use the coefficient `("Resolution" /. First[SystemInformation["Devices", "ScreenInformation"]]/72.)` as it is documented in the "Possible Issues" section on the Docs page for [`SystemInformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SystemInformation.html).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I really appreciate your guidance. I agree with the rounding and removed taskbar height, and the only thing that remained is `32.5`. Sidenote: I rewrote the full screenshot in the `NETLink` and it was ~65% faster!

Comment: You forgot to replace `displayInformation = First@SystemInformation["Devices", "ConnectedDisplays"]` with `displayInformation = First[SystemInformation["Devices", "ScreenInformation"]]` and `screenLimit = ("ScreenArea" /. displayInformation)[[All, 2]];`. :) It's sad that we still can't get rid of the "magic numbers". With `.NET` the situation is the same? In any case, publish that solution as well - it will be useful at least for educational purposes!

Comment: I updated my answer with the `currentNotebookImage[]` function which doesn't use any "magic" numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to take a fullscreen screenshot using the PIL [ImageGrab](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageGrab.html) module, that is already installed in many Python environments:

```
fullscreenShot[] := ExternalEvaluate["Python", "import PIL.ImageGrab
PIL.ImageGrab.grab()"]
```

Here is a function to take a screenshot of a specified screen rectangle using the same module:

```
screenShot = ExternalFunction["Python", "import PIL.ImageGrab
def screenshot(left_x, top_y, right_x, bottom_y): 
    return PIL.ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(left_x, top_y, right_x, bottom_y))"
  ]
```

> [image: out]

Here is a pure Python function to take a screenshot of the current active window on Windows<sup>[(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56572696/590388),[(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65573424/590388)</sup>:

```
activeWindowScreenShot[] := ExternalEvaluate["Python", "import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes
import PIL.ImageGrab
user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
handle = user32.GetForegroundWindow()
rect = wintypes.RECT()
user32.GetWindowRect(handle, ctypes.pointer(rect))
PIL.ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(rect.left,rect.top,rect.right,rect.bottom))"]
```

And here is a function to take a screenshot of the current Notebook window:

```
Clear[currentNotebookImage0]
currentNotebookImage0[margins_ : 6] := 
 Module[{screenInformation = First[SystemInformation["Devices", "ScreenInformation"]], 
   windowMargins = AbsoluteCurrentValue[WindowMargins], resolution, screenArea, width, 
   height, left, right, bottom, top}, 
   {resolution, screenArea} = {"Resolution", "ScreenArea"} /. screenInformation;
   {width, height} = Round[screenArea[[All, 2]]*resolution/72.];
   {{left, right}, {bottom, top}} = 
    Round[If[MatrixQ[windowMargins], 
      windowMargins + {{margins, margins}, {margins, margins}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}]*
     resolution/72.];
   {{left, right}, {top, bottom}} = {Clip[{left, width - right}, {0, width}], 
                                     Clip[{top, height - bottom}, {0, height}]};
   ExternalEvaluate["Python", <|"Command" -> "import PIL.ImageGrab
def screenshot(left_x, top_y, right_x, bottom_y): 
    return PIL.ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(left_x, top_y, right_x, bottom_y))", 
    "Arguments" -> {left, top, right, bottom}|>]]
```

The default value `6` for the parameter `margins` is taken from what returns `AbsoluteCurrentValue[WindowMargins]` when the Notebook window is maximized on my system (*Mathematica* 13.1.0 on Windows 10 x64):

```
AbsoluteCurrentValue[WindowMargins]
```

> ```
> -6
> ```

With *Mathematica* 12.3.1 on the same machine I get the value `-8`.

The value `-6` means that when the Notebook window is maximized, *Mathematica* thinks that the window is actually *cropped* by `6` printer's points from all sides. Translating into normal language, this means that the window is always *enlarged* by 6 printer's points on all sides as compared to its maximized size. The latter is equivalent in the meaning to the `ImageMargins` option of `Graphics` in *Mathematica*. Hence the `margins` parameter name.

These considerations are confirmed by comparing the values of the window width obtained from `AbsoluteCurrentValue[WindowSize]` and `AbsoluteCurrentValue[WindowMargins]` (output is for *Mathematica* 13.1.0):

```
windowMargins = AbsoluteCurrentValue[WindowMargins];
screenArea = "ScreenArea" /. First[SystemInformation["Devices", "ScreenInformation"]];
windowSize = AbsoluteCurrentValue[WindowSize];
screenArea[[All, 2]] - Total /@ windowMargins - windowSize
```

> ```
> {12., 44.25}
> ```

(for *Mathematica* 12.3.1 the output is `{16, 59}`).

We see that the window width reported by `AbsoluteCurrentValue[WindowSize]` is `6*2 = 12` printer's points smaller than the value obtain from `AbsoluteCurrentValue[WindowMargins]`. Hence we can calculate the value for the parameter `margins` from `AbsoluteCurrentValue[WindowSize]` as follows:

```
margins = If[MatrixQ[windowMargins], 
  (screenArea[[1, 2]] - Total[windowMargins[[1]]] - windowSize[[1]])/2, -windowMargins]
```

> ```
> 6.
> ```

With this definition, `currentNotebookImage0` can be rewritten as follows:

```
Clear[currentNotebookImage]
currentNotebookImage[] := 
 Module[{screenInformation = First[SystemInformation["Devices", "ScreenInformation"]], 
   windowMargins = AbsoluteCurrentValue[WindowMargins], margins, left, right, bottom, top,
   windowSize = AbsoluteCurrentValue[WindowSize], resolution, screenArea, width, height}, 
   {resolution, screenArea} = {"Resolution", "ScreenArea"} /. screenInformation;
   margins = If[MatrixQ[windowMargins], 
    (screenArea[[1, 2]] - Total[windowMargins[[1]]] - windowSize[[1]])/2, -windowMargins];
   {width, height} = Round[screenArea[[All, 2]]*resolution/72.];
   {{left, right}, {bottom, top}} = 
    Round[(windowMargins + margins*{{1, 1}, {1, 1}})*resolution/72.];
   {{left, right}, {top, bottom}} = {Clip[{left, width - right}, {0, width}], 
                                     Clip[{top, height - bottom}, {0, height}]};
   ExternalEvaluate["Python", <|"Command" -> "import PIL.ImageGrab
def screenshot(left_x, top_y, right_x, bottom_y): 
    return PIL.ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(left_x, top_y, right_x, bottom_y))", 
    "Arguments" -> {left, top, right, bottom}|>]]
```

The main advantage of this approach is that it **does not require "magic" numbers** and works perfectly well both with version 13.1.0 and 12.3.1:

```
currentNotebookImage[]
```

> [image: output]

---

It is easy to rewrite the great [`cCurrentNotebookImage[]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/272153/280) function by [Ben Izd](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/77079/ben-izd) using the new method for determining the window rectangle coordinates:

```
Needs["JLink`"];

LoadJavaClass /@ {"java.awt.Robot", "java.awt.Rectangle", 
   "java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream", "javax.imageio.ImageIO"};

Clear[cCurrentNotebookImage]
cCurrentNotebookImage[] := 
 Module[{screenInformation = First[SystemInformation["Devices", "ScreenInformation"]], 
   windowMargins = AbsoluteCurrentValue[WindowMargins], margins, left, right, bottom, top,
   windowSize = AbsoluteCurrentValue[WindowSize], resolution, screenArea, width, height},
  {resolution, screenArea} = {"Resolution", "ScreenArea"} /. screenInformation;
  margins = If[MatrixQ[windowMargins],
   (screenArea[[1, 2]] - Total[windowMargins[[1]]] - windowSize[[1]])/2, -windowMargins];
  {width, height} = Round[screenArea[[All, 2]]*resolution/72.];
  {{left, right}, {bottom, top}} = 
   Round[(windowMargins + margins*{{1, 1}, {1, 1}})*resolution/72.];
   {{left, right}, {top, bottom}} = {Clip[{left, width - right}, {0, width}], 
                                     Clip[{top, height - bottom}, {0, height}]};
  JavaBlock[robot = JavaNew["java.awt.Robot"];
   temp = JavaNew["java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream"];
   img = robot@
     createScreenCapture[
      JavaNew["java.awt.Rectangle", left, top, right - left, bottom - top]];
   ImageIO`write[img, "png", temp];
   ImportByteArray[ByteArray@Mod[temp@toByteArray[], 2^8], "PNG"]]]
```

---

There is an old but still working [`GUIScreenShot[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/GUIKit/ref/GUIScreenShot.html) from `` "GUIKit`" ``. To take a fullscreen screenshot, just evaluate:

```
Needs["GUIKit`"]
GUIScreenShot[]
```

To take a screenshot of the currently active Notebook, use the following function:

```
gCurrentNotebookImage[] := 
 Module[{screenInformation = First[SystemInformation["Devices", "ScreenInformation"]], 
   windowMargins = AbsoluteCurrentValue[WindowMargins], margins, left, right, bottom, top,
    windowSize = AbsoluteCurrentValue[WindowSize], resolution, screenArea, width, 
   height}, {resolution, screenArea} = {"Resolution", "ScreenArea"} /. screenInformation;
  margins = If[MatrixQ[windowMargins], 
   (screenArea[[1, 2]] - Total[windowMargins[[1]]] - windowSize[[1]])/2, -windowMargins];
  {width, height} = Round[screenArea[[All, 2]]*resolution/72.];
  {{left, right}, {bottom, top}} = 
   Round[(windowMargins + margins*{{1, 1}, {1, 1}})*resolution/72.];
  {{left, right}, {top, bottom}} = {Clip[{left, width - right}, {0, width}], 
                                    Clip[{top, height - bottom}, {0, height}]};
  GUIKit`GUIScreenShot[{{left, right}, {top, bottom}}]]
```